# ASP.net website use logged in Windows Credentials for CreateDirectory/File.Copy

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, impersonation

I am wondering if it's possible, and if so, how to have an ASP.net website on IIS use the windows credentials of the currently logged in user for Directory.CreateDirectory and File.Copy commands.

Currently my application works when running locally, however it doesn't work when hosted on the server using IIS.

It is set to only allow Windows Authentication and ASP.Net Impersonation on the server.

Directory.Exists() always returns false, I'm assuming because it is using the IIS user instead of the windows user which doesn't have permissions to access the server I am checking files on (other calls above fail too).  I don't want to supply user credentials as I would like each logged in user to only have permissions to preform what their credentials give and not what an admin credentials have permissions to.

Web.config authentication setup

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate ="true"/>
```

EDIT:
Ended up creating a service account with access to the folder and using that for the Application Pool.  When I get some more free time I might come back and try to figure out the issue (have a feeling it might have to do with a double-hop as I am going from IIS to another server not the IIS server itself.  But don't currently have permission to setup IIS Server as a delegate and test if that does anything).

Comment: What is the application pool that hosts your application in IIS set to run under? Also, please post how you are setting up authentication in your `web.config`

Comment: I have added authentication being used with web.config.  The application pool is set to run under ApplicationPoolIdentity.  Also I'm not sure if it's important or not, but WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name does return the logged in users domain name who should have permissions to do the above mentioned tasks on the external server folder.

Comment: Added some code to see what Identities were being returned.
Page.User.Identity.Name, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name all return my correct username with Domain.

System.Environment.UserName returns my correct username without Domain.  These are the same values returned on my local but the local allows the copy/creation.

Comment: Can you get more info on the error? Maybe try taking `Directory.Exists` temporarily out and run your file operation to see if you get an exception

Comment: It gives an error on Directory.CreateDirectory.  The error is 'System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.'  The path it is trying to write to is valid, just without the last directory that I am trying to create.  It works without issues if I add the same account to the ASP.NET Impersonation as a Specific User instead of using Authenticated User.

Comment: anything in the windows application or security event log?